# Confusion with derivation of average power formula

Tags: power, formula-derivation

I know that average power is equal to \$VmIm/2 * PF\$.

I can show that this is equivalent to \$(1/2)Re(VI^*)\$ by writing VI* in magnitude phase form.

However, I also know that complex power \$S = VI^* = P + jQ\$.

But then P = P/2!

What is going on here?

Comment: This would be more clear if you used [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for the formulas. (EE uses `\$` to start and end in-line math, instead of just `$`).

Comment: In particular, I'm not sure what you mean by "Vm" and "Im". Are these the magnitudes of V and I, or something else?

Comment: Sorry about that, I am not too familiar with the formatting.  Yes, Vm and Im are the maximum magnitudes of the voltage and current wave-forms ( v(t) = Vmax sin(wt + phi) ).  Also in our power course we take V phasor to be Vrms in magnitude, or Vmax / sqrt(2) for pure sinusoid.  The P = (1/2)Re(VI*) is an equation from my RF course.  I think the problem may have something to do with the conversion between time and phasor domain, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: Are you sure that the definitions of things are equivalent between courses? Prehaps you should check...

Comment: Be sure of pk,rms and avg units because 1/√2*1/√2=1/2 for V & I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue, thanks to your comments.  In my power course, the voltage phasor is defined as having RMS magnitude \$ V_{max} / \sqrt2 \$, while in my RF course, the voltage phasor is defined as having magnitude \$ V_{max} \$, where \$ v(t) = V_{max}cos(wt + \theta_v) \$.  So in my RF course, complex power would actually equal \$ (1/2)VI^* \$.  Therefore, \$ (1/2)Re(2S) = P \$.

Comment: Thank you for taking the trouble to come back and answer your question.